# How to find if input and variable is equal and if equal redirect to other file?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
<script>
 var IDCode = document.getElementById( "IDCode" );

 var user1 = FR1245

function AuthenticateFunction() {
 if (IDCode = user1) {
  alert("Access Successful!")
} else {
  alert("Access Denied!")
}
}
</script>
```

I want to make game and this is part of loading page, and if user enters his own game ID which will be set as variables, (here, FR1245), and I want if the user enters same code as set variable, I redirect him to next html file. But if not, he will stay in same page.
Please help...!

Comment: `IDCode === user1` missing equal symbols.  And this `var user1 = FR1245` will return undefined variable `FR1245` or something like that.

Comment: `var user1 = FR1245` will throw error.

Answer (score 1):

i correct your code for you

```
 var IDCode = document.getElementById( "IDCode" );
```

1- first of all : it is input element and u must use `IDCode.value` to check value

as  [ele](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1715121/ele) and [Maheer Ali](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9819146/maheer-ali) said:

```
 var user1 = "FR1245"
```

2- string must be between quotations like "string"

```
function AuthenticateFunction() {


 if (IDCode.value == user1) {
  alert("Access Successful!")
} else {
  alert("Access Denied!")
}
}
```

and for check your value you must use ==

Comment: You should add comments to the parts that were incorrect, to help them learn, instead of just copy/pasting in the corrected code.

Answer (score 0):

In your AuthenticateFunction() you are setting IDCode equal to user 1 by using a single ='s. Javascript has [several ways of checking equality:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness)

=== provides Strict Equality Comparison ("strict equality", "identity", "triple equals")
 == provides Abstract Equality Comparison ("loose equality", "double equals")

So your function should look like this:

```
function AuthenticateFunction(var one, var two) {
 if (one == two) {
    alert("Access Successful!")
 } else {
    alert("Access Denied!")
    window.location.replace("https://www.example.com")
 }
}
```

You can [redirect](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_redirect_webpage.asp) using window.location.replace and put all of this in a function in a js file such as:

```
function init(){
   var IDCode = document.getElementById( "IDCode" ).textContent;
   var user1 = "FR1245";

   AuthenticateUser(IDCode.value, user1);

}



 function AuthenticateFunction(var one, var two) {
    if (one == two) {
       alert("Access Successful!")
    } else {
       alert("Access Denied!")
       location.replace("https://www.example.com")
    }
 }
```

You could then place that init function in your body tag in any page you want to use it in so that it runs on page load such as:

```
<body onload="init()">
```